# Query to fetch multiple column from multiple table in symfony doctrine

Tags: symfony-3.1

I want to fetch data from multiple tables but i am not getting the correct query in symfony3 doctrine. Please help me.

I wrote my doctrine query as follows -

```
$q = $this-> getDoctrine()-> getManager();
        $query = $q->createQuery('
            SELECT p.firstname , p.lastname , l.language 
                    from UserBundle:Post p
                    from UserBundle:Language l
                    from UserBundle:UserLanguage u
                    where p.id = u.id and l.id = u.languageid
            ');

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am Finally able to solve this issue. This is the dql query to fetch different columns from multiple table with given condition.

```
$em = $this -> getDoctrine()->getManager();
$res = $em->createQuery(' SELECT  p.firstname , p.lastname , l.language from UserBundle:Post p Join UserBundle:UserLanguage u with p.id = u.userid join UserBundle:Language l with l.id = u.languageid');
$result = $res->getResult();

return $this->render('UserBundle:Default:showLanguage.html.twig', array('user' => $result));
```